# undefined symbol when make runtest in Caffe installation

Tags: ubuntu, caffe

There is a problem when I run the following command for the first time:

```
make runtest -j8
```

The output is as following:

```
.build_release/tools/caffe 
.build_release/tools/caffe: symbol lookup error: 
.build_release/tools/caffe: undefined symbol: _ZN6google16SetVersionStringERKSs Makefile:514: recipe for target 'runtest' failed 
make: *** [runtest] Error 127
```

However, when I run  `make runtest -j8` again:

There error message is different:
`*** Aborted at 1454750177 (unix time) try "date -d @1454750177" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7f144921d263 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0x706d742f) received by PID 15020 (TID 0x7f144d923780) from PID 1886221359; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f14444992f0 (unknown)
    @     0x7f144921d263 (unknown)
    @           0x47fb22 caffe::MakeTempDir()
    @           0x47fd73 caffe::MakeTempFilename()
    @           0x480419 testing::internal::TestFactoryImpl<>::CreateTest()
    @           0x89a0c3 testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x890cc5 testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0x890de5 testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0x894128 testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0x8943b7 testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x4667ff main
    @     0x7f1444484a40 (unknown)
    @           0x46de69 _start
Makefile:514: recipe for target 'runtest' failed
make: *** [runtest] Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

There is **no problem** when:

```
make all -j8
make test -j8
make pycaffe -j8
make matcaffe -j8
```

Additionally, when I run:

```
sh examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
```

There is **another error message**:

```
Creating lmdb... 
build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.bin: symbol lookup error: build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.bin: undefined symbol: _ZN6google15SetUsageMessageERKSs 
build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.bin: symbol lookup error: build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.bin: undefined symbol: _ZN6google15SetUsageMessageERKSs 
Done.
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Last time install cafffe, I have everything going smooth with Ubuntu 14. Now, I am using Ubuntu 15 (I must use ubuntu 15 since I faced another problem with ubuntu 14).

Is there anyone have encountered this issue?
Please help me to fix this issue. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Having this problem. Were you able to figure out an answer?

Comment: Actually, I figured out that Ubuntu 15 does not fully work with caffe version at that time. I had to come back to Ubuntu 14 (on another machine) after try to solving the problem a while. If you cannot install Ubuntu 14 (as hardware incompatible as mine), you can use torch, tensorflow, or theano which installation is much less painful.